# Why am I getting this error when using parse db?

Tags: parse-platform

I started getting this error without changing any code, and before it was working flawlessly. Any reason why this error is occurring and how to fix it?

`[Error]: Failed to run command eventually with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value."`

Comment: Parse is coming apart at the seams.  It seems like every day more things break.

Answer (score 1):

Some apps in Parse do not work.
The DB of mine is healthy, but api server on parse is unnormal.

see below link
https://status.parse.com/incidents/80mmfv10l1bv
(14:00~15:30 GMT+8)

Above incidents is marked as resolved, seems have another problem.

docs is not work https://parse.com/docs/.

Comment: Is there any setting changed of your app?

Comment: I cant get any result out of queries

Comment: I also get 504 error; i have been trying since 30 minutes.

can't even login at https://www.parse.com/login

Comment: Docs website is not work https://www.parse.com/docs/ . Maybe it still have problems, this website seems have error 2 https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/ .